# Tomcat requests take more than half a day, and still working

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

I had a working Java servlet, but now I sent it some request, and it stuck - as you can see in the screenshot, it is working for over 48000 seconds, which is over half a day:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-mMfXyy8lylYWZoN0FJQW5aUE0

This didn't happen before and it doesn't happen when I run this function directly from Java (without Tomcat).

a. How can I debug this and see where the Tomcat server is actually stuck?

b. Is there a way to kill these requests? (I tried restarting the webapp, but the requests kept running...)

P.S. I forgot to say that I'm on a Windows server.

Comment: You may use something like VisualVM/Jconsole to identify culprit thread. By analyzing thread dump, you may get some clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a. How can I debug this and see where the Tomcat server is actually stuck?**

1. Check your application logs (on tomcat), this should give you some clue if there is any issue with your application.
2. Take thread dumps and analyze (there are tools to analyze thread dumps). This helps a lot if your application is hanged.

**b. Is there a way to kill these requests? (I tried restarting the webapp, but the requests kept running...)**

You can list all java process by running below command on your unix host

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

This will list all java process along with their PID. You can kill individual process using kill command (kill -9 PID).

Comment: I forgot to say, I am on Windows. Here are the processes: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-mMfXyy8lylUFRHb3FjcjI0Wk0 There are two Tomcat processes, I deleted them but the requests didn't stop. The Tomcat processes re-appeared after several seconds.

Comment: It looks like Tomcat is running as a Windows service. Look under the Services tab for anything related to Tomcat and try to restart it from there.

Comment: OK, I managed to restart the Tomcat service, which obviously killed all the requests, but it also restarted all my other webapps... Is there a way to just stop specific requests without killing the entire service?

Comment: This can be done if the service is independent; check in task manager.